# Autocomplete по двум значениям

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete

Делаю поиск по имени в базе, получаю список объектов. 
Как мне настроить **autocomplete**, чтобы при выборе имени из списка, сохранялся **id** в **input value**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#patientName").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : contextPath + "/sp",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    minLength: 4,
                    success : function(data) {
                        var arr = [];
                        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            arr[i] = data[i].patientId + " " + data[i].name;
                        }
                        response(arr);
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Пока временно просто склеиваю **id** с именем.
Читал в документации про функцию select. Только все же нормально не понял как она работает.
Может в response еще **id** передавать ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#patientName").val(ui.item.id);
    return false;
}
```